# Downloading lots of large images then displaying in small UIImageViews in iPhone app. Do I need to resize to conserve memory?

Tags: iphone, memory-management, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm working on an app that downloads a series of images from a web server and displays them in the app. The images are about 615x725 from the server, but will only be displayed at about 200x230 in the app. The memory usage in my app is very high right now, and I'm getting regular memory warnings. They are being downloaded via this set of calls:

Synchronous ASIHTTPRequest (in GCD background thread) to NSData

```
[UIImage imageWithData:...]

[image forceLoad] (see below)

[UIImageView initWithImage:...]

[imageview setFrame:...]
```

Do I need to do any more than this to ensure that my memory isn't being hogged by unnecessarily large UIImage data? Or will the UIImageView handle this for me?

The forceload method:

```
- (void) forceLoad{
    const CGImageRef cgImage = [self CGImage];  

    const int width = CGImageGetWidth(cgImage);
    const int height = CGImageGetHeight(cgImage);

    const CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGImageGetColorSpace(cgImage);
    const CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(
                                                   NULL, /* Where to store the data. NULL = don’t care */
                                                   width, height, /* width & height */
                                                   8, width * 4, /* bits per component, bytes per row */
                                                   colorspace, kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), cgImage);
    CGContextRelease(context);
```

}

Comment: There is no way to let the server deliver smaller versions for your app? That might improve overall performance as well as solve your resizing problem.

Comment: Hi Nick, sorry I forgot to mention that it may be possible to get smaller images from the server, but I won't know for a while (I'm quite disconnected from the server admin) so I wanted to have this info as a backup in case I need it, plus for future reference in other apps.

Comment: If you can get hands on smaller images, do it! It's even good advice for normal websites, don't let clients(browsers) handle resizing, as this leads to higher bandwidth needed and cpu time on the client: user experience may suffer. So in a low bandwidth environment like the iphone this applies even more ;)

Comment: To get back to your memory usage problem: Have you run your app with the performance tool? It shows you easily what does chew on your resources the most.

Comment: Yeah I fully understand the various benefits of resizing the images at source before transfer via the net, but as I mentioned it may be out of my control. :)

Comment: By performance tool do you mean Instruments?

Comment: Yes, Instruments is your friend here :)

Comment: Yeah I'm running it and looking at allocations but it's not really telling me much except I'm using about 40Mb to load just my root view with a flowcover view containing 20 images plus a few buttons. Is there something else I should be looking at?

Comment: Well with Instruments you can pin down what exactly is eating up your memory. You can go quite deep and see what method created resources. The direction would be: If your app does run on low memory it has a reason and if it's your large collection of UIImages then you may need to come up with a solution to use only resources when actually needed. Like resizing images when they com in too large and add a file cache.

Comment: OK I've realised why. I was saving the image data into user defaults as a cache. Didn't realise that this would eat up memory as the cache fills. Putting the data in core data instead massively reduced usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can resize and image as follows, hope it helps

```
UIImage *newImage;
UIImage *olDImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData] ;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(200,230)); 
[olDImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0,200,230)];
newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); 
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: Thanks. Is this actually any different to passing it into a smaller sized UIImageVew?